# How to read a redirected flow in perl script

Tags: perl, redirect, pipe

I would like to parse the output of tcpdump command with a perl script in real time.

How can I read each line in my script when I'll call it like this :

```
tcpdump -i eth0 > ./parse.pl
```

Have a nice day

Comment: use pipe operator: `tcpdump ... | parse.pl`. And better use option `-l` to make output line buffered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` is a redirect to a file. That's not what you want - it'll overwrite your perl file.

What you need is a pipe:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 | ./parse.pl
```

This will connect the output of tcpdump to the `STDIN` of your perl. Which you can then do... whatever you like with.

E.g.:

```
while ( <STDIN> ) {
```